# call popupwindow from recyclerview

Tags: android

I am trying to call pop up window from my recyclerView adapter, I am getting a `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

here is the code which creates the popupwindow.

```
 private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {
        final View popupView =     

LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.times_popup, null);
        final PopupWindow pwindo = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        popupView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pwindo.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            }
        });

        btnClosePopup = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
        btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private View.OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pwindo.dismiss();

    }
};
```

and here is my RecyclerView class

public class DetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Restaurant> restaurant;
private List<Time> times;
private int rowLayout;
private Context context;
private PopupWindow pwindo;
private Button btnClosePopup;
private CoordinatorLayout rootLayout;
private LinearLayout root;



public class DetailViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    LinearLayout restaurantLayout;
   // TextView RestaurantTitle;
    TextView address1;
    TextView phone;
    TextView price;
    TextView menu_type;
    TextView rate;
    TextView open;
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    ImageView check;
    TextView offer;
    ImageButton info;







    public DetailViewholder(View v) {
        super(v);

        restaurantLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.general_information);
        ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        check = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tick);
        info = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.info);
        address1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
        phone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
        menu_type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_type);
        rate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        open = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hours);
        offer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.offer);
        root =(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        rootLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //onclick listener for the popup window
                initiatePopupWindow();
            }
        });
    }

    public void callplace(View view){
        String val = phone.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+val));
        context.startActivity(intent);
        Log.v("Calling", "Calling..."+val);
    }

}


public DetailsAdapter(List<Restaurant> restaurant,List<Time> times,int rowLayout,Context context) {
    this.restaurant = restaurant;
    this.times=times;
    this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public DetailsAdapter.DetailViewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
    return new DetailViewholder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DetailViewholder holder, final int position) {
    String Sadd = context.getResources().getString(R.string.addr);
    String Smen = context.getResources().getString(R.string.menu);
    String Spho = context.getResources().getString(R.string.phone);
    String Srat = context.getResources().getString(R.string.rate);
    String Scos = context.getResources().getString(R.string.cost);
    String Shou = context.getResources().getString(R.string.hours);
    String Stil = context.getResources().getString(R.string.till);
    String Soff = context.getResources().getString(R.string.offer);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    try {
        Date StartTime = dateFormat.parse(times.get(position).getStartTime());
        Date FinishTime = dateFormat.parse(times.get(position).getFinishTime());
        Date CurrentTime = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        if (CurrentTime.after(FinishTime) || CurrentTime.before(StartTime))
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Restaurant is currently closed");
            holder.check.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_red_500_18dp);
            holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Its open! yey!");
            holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.check.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_teal_600_18dp);


        }
    } catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    holder.ratingBar.setRating(1);
    holder.address1.setText(Sadd+restaurant.get(position).getAddress1().substring(0,20));
    holder.menu_type.setText(Smen+restaurant.get(position).getMenuType());
    holder.phone.setText(Spho+restaurant.get(position).getPhone());
    holder.rate.setText(Srat+restaurant.get(position).getRate());
    holder.price.setText(Scos+restaurant.get(position).getCost() +"€");
    holder.open.setText(Shou + times.get(position).getStartTime().substring(0,5)
            + Stil +times.get(position).getFinishTime().substring(0,5));
    holder.offer.setText(Soff+restaurant.get(position).getOffer());
    Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_info_blue_900_18dp)
            .fit()
            .into(holder.info);

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return restaurant.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to show popup in activity, using listener in adapter.

Just implement `DetailsAdapter.DetailListener` in your activity and show popup there

```
public class DetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    interface DetailListener {
        void onInfoClicked();
    }

    private DetailListener detailListener;

    public DetailsAdapter(List<Restaurant> restaurant,List<Time> times,int rowLayout,Context context, DetailListener detailListener) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
        this.times=times;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
        this.detailListener = detailListener;
    }

    ...

    public class DetailViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ...

    public DetailViewholder(View v) {
        super(v);

        ...

        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (detailsListener != null) {
                    detailsListener.onInfoClicked();
                }
            }
        });
    }      
}
```

Comment: Hi,sorry I am kind of a newbie in Android. Where exactly should I put the method? I had it inside  the method which is responsible for opening the window but the app just crashed,
I hav added the full method code.

Comment: Post your whole recycler view adapter and ViewHolder classes

Comment: I have added the full class code, I  hope it is any help.

Comment: I just did now the application is crashing instead of trying whats in the "try" statement
 `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

Comment: Try to add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

Comment: I am using a popup window on another activity and it is working fine. I am just having troubles  when I am calling the popup activity through an Adapter class instead of the main class.

PS: I have added it to permission, still throwing the error in try statement.

Comment: So, if it works in activity, just use listener to inform your activity. I've updated post

Comment: What I meant was. The popup window is working on a separate activity which is not connected to a recyclerview. So i didnt need to add the permission to the manifest.

Comment: I understood, just implement the listener in the activity, the recyclerview connected to and show popup there. Additionally you can pass necessary params to `onInfoClicked()` method

Comment: I have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have Fixed the issue by referring the inflator to my parent.getContext() instead of the "context" variable,

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```